# How to Install a C/C++ compiler in Ubuntu 14.04LTS?

Tags: compiler

Is there a need to install a C/C++ compiler in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS? Where to write the program? How to compile the same?

Comment: do this `sudo apt-get install g++`  you don't need a compiler to write programs, only to compile / build.

Answer (score 13):

**install compiler(s)**

- C and C++ and make etc.

  ```
  sudo apt-get install build-essential
  ```
- Fortran

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gfortran g77
  ```

**to edit source code**

use any texteditor. From the graphical user interface for example use `kate`. From the commandline use `nano`:

```
nano main.cpp
```

**to compile**

```
g++ main.cpp -o main
```